# What's the physical significance of a sinusoid's Bode magnitude?

Tags: bode-plot, sinusoidal

What's the physical significance of a sinusoid's Bode plot's magnitude, at the sinusoid center frequency?

Example: `sin(wt)`, with w = 62.8 rad/s = 10 Hz. This has amplitude 1.
The Laplace transform is `w^2 / (s^2 + w^2)`.

1. Where does the ~150 dB Magnitude peak come from?
   How does the peak correlate with the input sinusoid amplitude?

It's unclear what the peak represents, even though it's obvious the amplitudes correlate: a doubling of input amplitude (eg 2*sin(wt) ) would cause a 6 dB positive shift in the bode output, which is 2x in magnitude...although I would have thought it'd give a 3 dB shift.

2. Why does the Magnitude bode of `2*sin(wt)` shift by +6 dB, and not 3 dB? Somehow it's related to power vs fraction conversion (`10*log()` vs `20*log()`, but i thought 2x would give 3 dB amplitude.

[image: Bode of 10 Hz sinusoid]

Comment: Bode plots are typically used to analyze frequency and phase response of a system, or rather, the transfer function of a system. It is a bit unclear why would you even want a Bode plot of a sine wave, as it makes little sense. Can you explain why?

Comment: 20*log(2) = 6.02 dB

Comment: Thanks; And sure, I can elaborate. See my answer below to Miron's comment. Ultimately, I'm looking to understand the response of a system to (say) a sinusoid, by analyzing the final bode plots. But I realized that I'm unclear on what physically I would be seeing. Anyway, see my elaboration in that response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peak is actually infinite, the reason you are seeing 143 dB is due to limited precision of the software. In transfer functions (you can think of your sin(ωt) as a transfer function taking a DC level in and a sine wave out), every position on the s plane where the numerator of the transfer function is 0 is called a "Zero" and every position where the denominator is 0 is called a "Pole", which causes the result of the transfer function to approach infinity. You have a pole at s = +-ω·sqrt(-1), which shows up on the plot.

https://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf

2nd question: 10·log() is used for comparing the ratio between power levels, 20·log() is used for comparing voltage levels. You can think of doubling the amplitude of the sine wave, as doubling the voltage level of the signal. Now, according to P = V<sup>2</sup>/R, doubling the voltage level quadruples the power if you were sending that voltage through a resistive load. Doubling is +3 dB, quadrupling is +6 dB.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

Comment: "The peak is actually infinite" Interesting, thanks. Then, how can someone determine the behavior of a transfer function when a sinusoid is sent through it? Eg, if there a low pass filter H(s), and a sinusoid D(s) is attenuated by it, the response is H(s)*D(s). Say the goal is to determine attenuation. Using Bode plots, how would I find the sinusoid's output amplitude, if the starting baseline is infinite amplitude? Physically, this would be easy: amplitude of Asin(wt) is A, H(s) attenuation at w is xyz dB, so output amplitude A' = -xyz dB x A. How can I find A' using Bode(H*D)?

Comment: I will clarify the above: of course, the bode of the LPF defines the attenuation response of the sinusoid. I should clarify with a more general example: some arbitrary signal R. If R is decomposed into its sinusoid components and passed through the filter, phase information between the sin-components is lost...so i think it's not the same as running R's full TF through the LPF via H*R, and looking at bode(H*R) to examine the resulting response.

Comment: @PB You would use the Bode Plot of the attenuator for that and read the value at the corresponding Sine frequency.

Comment: Thanks @tobalt. But see my previous comment (the one above your reply) about an arbitrary signal as the more general case. What then?

Comment: Then different frequency components of this arbitrary signal will be affected differently by this attenuator @PB you can reach the response for each component from the Bode plot of the attenuator.

Comment: Thanks tobalt. But is using the bode the same response as a composite signal filtering, if the phase of the signal components is not known? Eg "If R is decomposed into its sinusoid components and passed through the filter, phase information between the sin-components is lost...so i think it's not the same as running R's full TF through the LPF via HR, and looking at bode(HR) to examine the resulting response."

Answer (score 1):

As already said, the Laplace transform of a pure sine has a pole (=zero denominator) just at the frequency of the sine. Actually there's 2 poles, numerically at s-values = +jw and -jw where j is the imaginary unit and w=2(Pi)f.

The peak reflects the fact that all signal power is centered to a single frequency assuming the sine has never started and will never stop, it only has existed and will exist. A sine which has started at some time moment and stops at some other time does not have that infinity, but a peak can be still substantial if the duration of the signal is long when compared to the oscillation period.